# IoT Central REST API to query devices

Tags: azure, azure-iot-central

Under this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/core/howto-query-with-rest-api) Microsoft describes how to use the REST-API to query the stored data from IoT Central.
It is a POST

```
https://{your app subdomain}.azureiotcentral.com/api/query?api-version=1.1-preview
```

and the body with

```
"query": "SELECT $id, $ts, temperature, humidity FROM urn:modelDefinition:fupmoiu28b:ymju9efv9 WHERE WITHIN_WINDOW(P1D)"
```

This works fine, but how do I query the data for a device model with components?
I still get the Error:

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "NotFound",
    "message": "The requested resource was not found. You can contact support at https://aka.ms/iotcentral-support. Please include the following information. Request ID: 2383fajc, Time: Wed, 08 Dec 2021 15:32:22 GMT.",
    "requestId": "2383fajc",
    "time": "Wed, 08 Dec 2021 15:32:22 GMT"
}
```

}

Is this in general not possible?

Thank you
init5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was quite trivial and was already posted here by someone (thanks to the person who was able to answer the question for me). Unfortunately, I no longer see the answer here, so I am posting the solution here again so that others with this problem can find a solution here.

```
"query": "SELECT your_telemtry, model.your_telemetry FROM device template ID WHERE WITHIN_WINDOW(P1D)"
```

The "trick" here is to add the module name infront of the telemetry from the  module.
Hope that helps ;)

Comment: have a look at the document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/core/howto-query-with-rest-api#select-clause